# Why are my Facebook pictures losing quality?

Tags: facebook

My Facebook pictures seem to be losing quality. I compared one of them with an old screenshot on Online Image Diff and there was a lot of difference. Is there a way to get my original images back?

Comment: Do you mean that you uploaded photos to FB then deleted the originals? And now you are expecting to download the originals from FB?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook never stores your original image (and, in some cases, never even sees your original image -- the FB uploader compresses overly-large images before even sending them to the Facebook servers).

Since Facebook doesn't have your original image, you can't get your original image back from Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

When uploading to Facebook, make sure you've exported the photos resized to 2048px at the longest edge (most photoeditors will allow you to just set that), and jpeg quality to about 60%. Then when you upload to Facebook make sure you hit the high quality option and start uploading. There will still be some compression but it won't be as gnarly. Most of the quality compression will be done by the photo editor and not by Facebook when doing it this way, which preserves you some quality. Good luck!

Comment: So...Facebook resizes with a fixed maximum file size, then? Or why is it that ~60% exports work the best?

Comment: Which "high quality option"? Where? And what source(s) did you use to answer that question?

Comment: I can't remember the sources anymore as it's some time ago that I had to do this. But just Google it and check for reputable photography blogs and sites. The high quality tick box I'll have to look for, my pc is updating at the minute. And why did I get a downvote? Did I not answer OP's question correctly?

Comment: @StenMartens Maybe because you didn't answer the question?  You can't get the original images back after uploading to FB.  It wasn't me that downvoted your answer but I can see why.